# GREP: Excluding file names with specific pattern while including specific file extension

Tags: perl, grep

I'm just starting to learn Perl and am having difficulty using the **grep** function. Specifically, I want to exclude file names with the numbers 0-9 in their names, but output only those files with the .png extension. I've figured out how to exclude the file names with numbers, but I need help with how to include only files with the .png extension.

Here's my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
opendir(DIR, $dir);
@files = grep (!/[1-9]/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

foreach $file (@files) {
   print "$file\n";
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Packera_glabellus.png
Leucojum_aestivum.png
Reynoutria_japonica.png
Agalinis_purpurea.png
.DS_Store
```

As you can see, ".DS_Store" does not have a .png extension. Please suggest a **grep** expression that  outputs only un-numbered file names with the .png extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude files with any numbers in their names, modify the `grep` line to:

```
@files = grep (/^\D*\.png\z/,readdir(DIR));
```

This only returns file names that starts with any (or zero) non-digit characters, and is followed by a `.png` ending.

If you want to exclude files containing just 1-9 in their names, change the regex:

```
@files = grep (/^[^1-9]*\.png\z/,readdir(DIR));
```

Comment: End-of-string is `\z`, not `$`. Using `$` allows files with the extension `.png␊`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, I've learned new knowledge too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```perl
@files = grep {!/[0-9]/ && /\.png\z/i} readdir(DIR);
```

This matches png files without numbers in their names and `/i` allows the extension to be either case (upper or lowercase).

Comment: End-of-string is `\z`, not `$`. Using `$` allows files with the extension `.png␊`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) can help with your task

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

my @files = grep !/\d/, glob("$dir/*.png");

say for @files;
```